# Set Mattermost status automatically when I'm in a meeting or call

Tags: microsoft-outlook, instant-messaging, microsoft-teams

My workplace uses Mattermost for instant messaging, and Microsoft Teams for voice/video calls. Sometimes I finish a Teams call with someone, to find that an hour ago someone messaged me on Mattermost, and I missed it because I was in a call. I'd like to at least warn them by setting my status when I'm not able to reply to messages.

So, I'd like a way to automatically set my status on Mattermost to Away or Do Not Disturb when I'm in a Teams call - or when my Outlook calendar says I'm busy. Is there any way to do this? I've tried googling, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Have you asked your IT Administrator for assistance?

Comment: You may contact the support of Mattermost for some information.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible at the moment. There is a suggestion for it [here](https://mattermost.uservoice.com/forums/306457-general/suggestions/33149530-allow-mattermost-to-pick-up-my-availability-status).